# Beside paypal what are the other payment services a web app should support?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

The goal here is maximum conversion of users to an application. I tried to research paypal's market share to see what other services cover the remainder. Is the remaining market share large enough to make it worthwhile to cover other services? Which services are currently 2nd and 3rd to paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That differs per country. In the netherlands ideal is a must, google wallet would be nice.
Every country has it's own EFT online banking system with options to pay in web stores.
Just search with the banks of the country of your target group what they use the most and implement their payment api.